# Component which apply default parameters to other component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorise

I am using Blazorise, which provide multiple base components such as `<Button>`, with multiple parameters.
I would like to create a simple component which would render a `<Button>` with one or two parameters hard-coded (such as `Color="Colors.Primary")` and then pass the rest of the parameters onto the `<Button>`.

This is what I would like to be able to write:

```razor
<PrimaryButton Outline>Text</Button>
```

I would like to achieve this without having to manually set all parameters available from `<Button>` in `PrimaryButton.razor`. I have been looking for a way to do this for some time but can't find anything. Is It even possible?

I already tried inheriting from `Button` and writing `<Button @attributes="@Attributes" Color="Colors.Primary">` but the implicit parameters are discarded.

Answer (score 2):

I think you still have to pass them as parameters by adding them to your custom component. For instance you could do a button with `Color` and `Outline` set but pass on the `Block` parameter.

```razor
/* PrimaryButton.razor */
<Button Color="Color.Primary" Outline="true" Block="@Block">@ChildContent</Button>

@code {
  [Parameter] public bool Block { get; set;}
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

You could then use that new component as

```razor
<PrimaryButton Block="true">Some Text</PrimaryButton>
```

Comment: I would really like to avoid doing that. I would be really surprised and disappointed that Blazor does not allow this, but it seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Attribute Splatting" for this

suppose your Base Component is defined

```html
<h1>Base Component</h1>
<div>Param1 = @Param1</div>
<div>Param2 = @Param2</div>
@code
{
    [Parameter] public string Param1 { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

And you want to pre-populate Param1, so you create a new MyComponent

```html
<BaseComponent Param1="predefined" @attributes=Attributes/>
@code
{
  [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues=true)] 
  public Dictionary<string,object> Attributes { get; set; }       
}
```

Now, you can use MyComponent in place of BaseComponent, and if you do not supply a value for Param1, it will be predefined (literally that value in this case)

So this markup:

```html
<BaseComponent Param1="base" Param2="component"/>

<MyComponent Param1="my" Param2="component"/>

<MyComponent Param2="component"/>
```

Produces this output:

> ## Base Component
>
> Param1 = base
> Param2 = component
>
> ## Base Component
>
> Param1 = my
> Param2 = component
>
> ## Base Component
>
> Param1 = predefined
> Param2 = component

See a live sample on BlazorRepl : https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QEvucNFB408fLIXd18

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation. I tried this but it doesn't work and I think it's because the component I want to render with some predefined parameters is a component that also uses attribute splatting. I want to do that with the Button component from Blazorise.