# Inherit from InputBase in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm creating a custom component that derives from InputBase...

So far here's my code for MyCustomInput.razor:

```
@inherits InputBase<string>
<input id="@id" @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" class="@CssClass" value="@CurrentValue"
```

I want to be able to use the component either:

```
<MyCustomInput @bind-Value="user.Telephone" ...
```

Or

```
<MyCustomInput @bind-Value="user.Telephone" @bind-Value:event="oninput" ...
```

To accomplish this what should I change to MyCustomInput ?

Thanks very much for your help !

Cheers,

Raphaël

Comment: So easy. Really. Two steps. You should to bind your custom control to `value`, like this: `<input @bind-value="Value"` and override `protected override bool TryParseValueFromString`. See [Option 2 (recomended): Through inheritance from InputBase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933827/842935) section.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this out !!!

Answer (score 4):

`MyCustomInput.razor`

```
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputText
<input @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" @bind="@CurrentValueAsString" @bind:event="oninput" />
```

Usage:

```
<MyCustomInput @bind-Value="user.Telephone" class="@CssClass" id="@id" />
```

No need to override `TryParseValueFromString` your using a string.
The html attributes `id` and `class` will be passed via splatting `@attributes="@AdditionalAttributes`

Answer (score 2):

You can nest components within other components. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64432708/12189828) for an example of how to do so.